# I'm making a syntax highlighter and am having trouble coloring text between quotes

Tags: c++

I have the program iterate through the line to find a ". If it does, start up another for loop that goes from the end of the string in to find another ". When it does, it will check if it is at the same location as the first iterator. If it is, it will insert the "end-text-coloration" line, but if it is not, it will insert the "begin-text-coloration" line. I am not sure if my problem lies within my logic or code :/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getLength(string a) {
    return a.length();
}

int main () 
{
    string formStart = "\033[1;32m";
    string  formEnd = "\033[0m";
    string line;
    size_t pos;

    ifstream myFile ("opentest.cpp");

    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while(getline(myFile,line)) {
            len = getLength(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                if (line[i] == '"') 
                    len = getLength(line);

                for (int n = len; n >= i; n--) {
                    if (line[n] == '"' && n == i) {
                        cout << "hit end" << endl;
                        line.insert(i, formEnd);
                    } else {
                        cout << "hit start" << endl;
                        line.insert(i, formStart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cout << line << endl;   
        myFile.close();

    } else {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code does not have correct matching braces.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Where?

Comment: There are total 9 `{` where as 10 `}`. You probably need to re-paste the code with proper indentation.

Comment: Thank you, just found the bugger.  Edited to fix.

Comment: You started coding too soon. Your algorithm is wrong. Work it out on paper before you write any code.

Comment: I actually have... Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: Better algorithm could be this one: go from start to end, when `"` comes up toggle coloring. If this is wrong for your case then we don't have enough information about your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help guys.  I figured it out.  My loop was not catching the second " because it was inserting the format string before the first one.  Here is my solution complete with line termination check:

```
while(getline(myFile,line))
            {      
                    int placehold;
                    bool issecond = false;
                    len = getLength(line);
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            if (line[i] == '"') {
                                    switch(issecond){
                                            case false:
                                                    line.insert(i, formStart);
                                                    issecond = true;
                                                    i += 8;
                                                    placehold = i;
                                                    break;
                                            case true:
                                                    line.insert((i+1), formEnd);
                                                    issecond = false;
                                                    i+=3;
                                                    break;
                                    }
                                    len = getLength(line);
                            }

                            if (i == (len-1) && issecond == true){
                                    line.insert(placehold, formEnd);
                                    issecond = false;
                            }
                    }




                    cout << line << endl;  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the `if` should be something like this:

```
if (line[n] == '"')
{
    if (n == i) {
        cout << "hit end" << endl;
        line.insert(i, formEnd);
    } else {
        cout << "hit start" << endl;
        line.insert(i, formStart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this seems to put me in an infinite loop.